# Input value "undefined" Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have some trouble with nodejs and express, I'm actually trying to get the value of inputs from a view "inscription.ejs" but when I question the object "req" he return null values.

The structure of the project :

- app 
  -- controller 
  ------- home.js 
  ------- user.js 
  ------- book.js 
  -- modele 
  ------- modele.js 
  -- views 
  ------- some views ejs
- config 
  -- routes.js
- public
- server.js
- package.json
- node-modules

In server.js i just make a call of routes.js in order to load the routes with this lines :

> require('./config/routes')(app)

In routes.js I make different calls in the controller folder and actually everything work :

```
var user = require('../app/controller/user');
var book = require('../app/controller/book');
var home = require('../app/controller/home');

/**
 * Expose
 */

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/home', home.index)
    app.get('/home/inscription', home.inscription)
    app.post('/home/inscription', user.addUser)
}
```

Here the problem, in user.js :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var models = require('../entity/modele')(mongoose);

exports.addUser = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params);
    res.render('user');
};
```

When i send the form, I'm redirect in the template "user.ejs" but in the console the value of inputs are undefined.
I tried to use :

> req.body.name 
>   req.param(name)

No result.

Answer (score 0):

check configuration of   body-parser middleware in server.js file

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})
 // your route configuration here
```

Answer (score 0):

Take in consideration that if you are passing the information through the URL, you will use `params`, however if your are passing the information using JSON, you will use `req.body` when you will destructure it instead of `req.params`.